# How to select a specific object from the action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

How do I select a specific object from the action class when pulling up multiple objects in JSP.

From my action class I pass through Struts five of the same object. In JSP how would I select a specific object and property of the object to display on page. I have tried putting various values and names in the `<s:form>` tag but I have yet to figure out how to do it. A push in the corrected *direction* would be welcome.

Comment: I have a for loop with an if statement inside

for(Walkthrough w: walkthroughs)
  {
   if(runThrough==1)
   {
    Walkthrough sectionOne = new Walkthrough();
    sectionOne.set_id(w.get_id());
    sectionOne.set_areaName(w.get_areaName());
    sectionOne.set_walkthroughText(w.get_walkthroughText());
   }

and I have runThrough++ at the end

Comment: What displayed then you have put something in the tag? Could you post your JSP?

Comment: <s:form action="WalkthroughAction" name="sectionOne">
   <s:property value="sectionOne_walkthroughText"/>
  </s:form>
Nothing at all diplays but the page does not break either.

Comment: @user1698308 Please edit the *question* with updated info; code in comments is useless. You can notify a question asker with a comment, but use an `@` tag so they're notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<s:iterator value="walkthroughs" >
    <s:property value="id"/><br>
    <s:property value="areaName"/><br>
...
</s:iterator>
```

And you should rename your getter methods to be bean compartible.

```
getId(), getAreaName()
```

Comment: I am wanting each object to be able to be styled differently would this allow for that?

Comment: @user1698308 You could style them whatever you like inside the iterator tag.